# change the value if drop down to login user?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, asp.net-membership

I have test list on drop down list in user control. I am trying to change the selected tech to loggedin  user but it give me 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = Membership.GetUser().UserName;
    ddl_techsList.SelectedItem.Text = username;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not be having the item in drop down with given text i.e. UserName in your case. So first check if you have that element then if you find it then it should be selected.

```
ddl_techsList.ClearSelection();
ListItem li = ddl_techsList.Items.FindByText( defaultText));

if(li != null)
    li.Selected = true;
```

**Update**

if the dropdown list is in some other user control.

```
DropDownList ddl_techsList = (DropDownList)YourUserControlInstanceID.FindControl("ddl_techsList");
ddl_techsList.ClearSelection();
ListItem li = ddl_techsList.Items.FindByText( defaultText));

if(li != null)
    li.Selected = true;
```

Comment: the problem is ddl_techsList inside user_control